# Проблема с библиотекой Python для редактирования .DXF файлов

Tags: python

Каким способом можно изменить стиль на новый в более чем 3000 .dxf файлах (координаты глубин). Ручная обработка или открытие каждого файла в среде Autocad - физически не допустима.  Всё что нашёл на просторах сети - библиотеку ezdxf - Python. Но до сих пор не нашёл в её описании - простой эффективны способ замены всех примитивов в виде М-текст - глубина, на нужные мне параметры стиля. Есть ли сторонние библиотеки для обработки .dxf сторонними библиотеками согласно моей задаче?

```
[![import ezdxf
from ezdxf.enums import TextEntityAlignment
 
# The TEXT entity is a DXF primitive and is supported in all DXF versions.
# The argument setup=True creates standard linetypes and text styles in the
# new DXF document.
doc = ezdxf.new("R12", setup=True)
msp = doc.modelspace()
 
# Use method set_placement() to define the TEXT alignment, because the
# relations between the DXF attributes 'halign', 'valign', 'insert' and
# 'align_point' are tricky.
msp.add_text("A Simple Text").set_placement(
    (2, 3),
    align=TextEntityAlignment.MIDDLE_RIGHT
)
 
# Using a predefined text style:
msp.add_text(
    "Text Style Example: Liberation Serif",
    height=0.35,
    dxfattribs={"style": "LiberationSerif"}
).set_placement((2, 6), align=TextEntityAlignment.LEFT)
 
doc.saveas("test.dxf")][1]][1]
```